# Doctrine Nested set. Выбрать родителей у детей, которых есть определенные значения в связанных таблицах

Tags: sql, symfony, doctrine, nested-sets

Есть таблица с категориями -  category (nested set),  у которой есть связь с таблицей "товары" - product. Есть категории вернего уровня, например одежда,  потом в промежутке может быть верхняя, зимняя и т.д. На самом нижнем уровне категория "куртки". У записи с товаром, поле category_id имеет связь с низшим уровнем в таблице category. Как выбрать категории самого верхнего уровня если у его детей в связанных товарах поле равно определенному значению?

Comment: Первым запросом получить правые, левые ключи низовых элементов. По полученным ключам составить фильтр для второго запроса

Comment: Dmitry Kozlov, хотелось бы получить это одним запросом

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Критерий отбора был такой: 
Показать те родительские категории (уровень 0), у детей которых, записи связанных товаров были не старше 7 дней.

Я поступил так:

1. join товаров
2. join родителей
3. where дата создания товара не позднее 7 дней
4. группировка по родителям (чтобы избежать дублирования), сортировка по наименованию родителей

   ```
   $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('node')
              ->select('node', 'parent')
              ->join('node.parent', 'parent')
              ->join('node.product', 'p')
              ->where('parent.lvl = 0')
              ->andWhere('p.created_at >= :criteria')
              ->setParameter('criteria', new \DateTime('-7 days'))
              ->groupBy('parent.id')
              ->orderBy('parent.title', 'ASC')
   ;
   $query = $qb->getQuery();
   $result = $query->getArrayResult();
   ```

В итоге я получил вот массив вот такого вида:

```
    array (size=2)
     0 => 
         array (size=8)
           'id' => int 6
           'title' => string 'Мобильные телефоны' (length=35)
           'photo' => null
           'slug' => string 'Mobilnye_Telefony' (length=17)
           'lft' => int 10
           'rgt' => int 11
           'lvl' => int 1
           'parent' => 
               array (size=7)
                  'id' => int 2
                  'title' => string 'Смартфоны и гаджеты' (length=36)
                  'photo' => string 'ct/a455d2b2d78f75046b090131de3991e4.jpg' (length=39)
                  'slug' => string 'Smartfony_I_Gadzhety' (length=20)
                  'lft' => int 7
                  'rgt' => int 12
                  'lvl' => int 0
    1 => 
        array (size=8)
           'id' => int 3
           'title' => string 'Телевизоры' (length=20)
           'photo' => null 
           'slug' => string 'Televizory' (length=10)
           'lft' => int 2
           'rgt' => int 3
           'lvl' => int 1
           'parent' => 
                array (size=7)
                   'id' => int 1
                   'title' => string 'Электроника' (length=22)
                   'photo' => string 'ct/7f38e939e071b5225b8e8e003b8559fd.jpg' (length=39)
                   'slug' => string 'Elektronika' (length=11)
                   'lft' => int 1
                   'rgt' => int 6
                   'lvl' => int 0
```

Далее, предварительно написанной функцией:

```
$outputArray = [];
foreach ($inputArray as $key => $value) {
    array_push($outputArray, $value[$keys]);
}

    return $outputArray;
```

, я "выдрал" содержимое всех "parent" в новый массив:

```
array (size=2)
 0 => 
    array (size=7)
  'id' => int 2
  'title' => string 'Смартфоны и гаджеты' (length=36)
  'photo' => string 'ct/a455d2b2d78f75046b090131de3991e4.jpg' (length=39)
  'slug' => string 'Smartfony_I_Gadzhety' (length=20)
  'lft' => int 7
  'rgt' => int 12
  'lvl' => int 0
 1 => 
array (size=7)
  'id' => int 1
  'title' => string 'Электроника' (length=22)
  'photo' => string 'ct/7f38e939e071b5225b8e8e003b8559fd.jpg' (length=39)
  'slug' => string 'Elektronika' (length=11)
  'lft' => int 1
  'rgt' => int 6
  'lvl' => int 0
```